# 0 added to listbox2 display when item selected in Listbox1

Tags: vb.net, listbox

1.When I select an item from my listbox1 it shows information about the item in listbox2. However, when I click an item in listbox1 it shows me the info and adds a 0 to the end of it in listbox2. How do I get rid of the 0 or what am I doing that is causing this? I think it is displaying the index number perhaps. Here is my code-

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then ListBox2.Items.Add("60137" & ListBox2.Items.Add("60138"))
```

2.Also, How would I clear List2 when I choose a different item in list1 so that they dont both populate list2 at the same time?

Comment: Why are you using a ListBox for the related item?  A ListBox is meant for displaying multiple items that the user can select from.  It seems like a Label would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ignoring the fact that this is a horrible design...

Change:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then ListBox2.Items.Add("60137" & ListBox2.Items.Add("60138"))
```

To:

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then 
    ListBox2.Items.Clear
    ListBox2.Items.Add("60137")
End If
```

Here is an alternative approach:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim petA As New Pet
        petA.Name = "Puss in Boots"
        petA.Species = "Cat"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(petA)

        Dim petB As New Pet
        petB.Name = "Nemo"
        petB.Species = "Fish"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(petB)

        Dim petC As New Pet
        petC.Name = "Rango"
        petC.Species = "Lizard"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(petC)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Dim P As Pet = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Pet)
            Label1.Text = P.Species
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Pet

    Public Name As String
    Public Species As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I know it is rather crude. What would you suggest using in place of this? And it still adds a 0 eg "601370" I am willing to learn :) Thank you still.